# Get an individual record using ember-model with 'find'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an app where I am using [ember-model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model) and I am unable to get a single model when passing anything other than an ID into find.

My code will make more sense:

```
currentMembership: function() {
  var mem = Membership.find({ user_id: 1, organization_id: 1, limit: 1 });
  return mem.get('firstObject');
}.property()
```

I have tried using `fetch` as well but to no avail:

```
currentMembership: function() {
  return Membership.fetch({ user_id: 1, organization_id: 1, limit: 1 }).then(
    function(results) {
      return results.get('firstObject');
    }
  );
}.property()
```

Is there a way to do this where we can force the response to build off the first object and return a single model instead of a recordarray?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this yourself as `fetchOne`, but this is not something built into Ember Model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it wrong, you should use {userId: 1, organizationId: 1}